How many ways can you spend your tokens on an amusement park?
I can not get my head around this problem:

You are going to an amusement park:


There are four attractions: $\bf 1$) haunted house, $\bf 2$) roller coaster, $\bf 3$) a carousel and $\bf 4$) a water ride.
You buy $25$ tokens.
Each attraction cost $3$ tokens each ride, except the roller coaster that costs $5$.
Obviously, you want to ride each ride
at least once, but the order of the rides does not matter.
In how many ways can you spend your tokens ?.
You may have some remaining tokens in the end of the day.

I tried to solve it by looking at the remaining rides after all rides have been visited once. This can be illustrated with the equation
$$3r_1+3r_2+3r_3+5r_4\le 11$$ where $r_n$ corresponds to the different rides and $r_4$ is the roller coaster,
We know that $$r_4\in \{0,1,2\}$$ which gives us the equations
$$\begin{cases}
3(r_1+r_2+r_3)\le 11 \text{(case. I)}\\
3(r_1+r_2+r_3)\le 6 \text{(case. II)}\\
3(r_1+r_2+r_3)\le 1 \text{(case. III)}
\end{cases}$$
I was trying to start with eqn. I and convert it to an equation by adding an extra variable for the unused tokens at the end of the day, $\xi$.
So for example we can derive an equation from Case. I:
$$3(r_1+r_2+r_3)+\xi=11\quad(4)$$
The next natural step for me would be to divide the transformed equation (4) by 3. But this is something I do not know how to handle - obviously $11/3$ is not an integer number, and how would I handle $\xi$?
The answer key for this problem (which is from Per Alexanderssons Discrete Mathematics, question 41), claims that the equation derived from case 1 (the equation I call (4))
can be rewritten as $$h + c + w + r = 3$$ where $h,c,w$ represents the haunted house, carousel and water ride and the $r$ representes the remaining tokens at the end of the day.
Why can it be rewritten like this?

How can $h, c, w ..$ represent entities and the right hand side represent money  ( tokens)

For each of your three cases, the left hand side is a multiple of $3$, so the value of $\xi \pmod 3$ is known to be the right hand side $\mod 3$.  For case I, write $\xi = 3\xi' + (11 \pmod 3) = 3\xi' + 2$, yielding
$$3(r_1+r_2+r_3)+(3\xi'+2)=11,$$
which becomes
$$r_1+r_2+r_3+\xi'=3.$$

Thank you! Now I understand why we can do as the answer key suggests.
